# How do fileless shortcuts work in Windows?

Tags: windows, shortcut, shortcut-file

What is the nature of shortcuts of the second kind, how are they created and how do they actually work? How does a developer create a shortcut of this kind for his application?

[image]

Comment: This should really be on SuperUser.

Comment: @user12321: not at all, since users cannot create those kind of shortcuts.

Comment: @Joey It hasn't got anything to do with programming though

Comment: The answer will be an API call, I'm fairly sure of that.

Comment: [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/10/10375909.aspx) explains what they are ... essentially you just set the target to a shell object, not to a file system path. I've never really dealt with the Shell APIs, so someone else has to answer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144096%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: This *is* a programming question; creating an installer is part of a programmers job, and creating shortcuts is part of that.

Comment: There just are people who love to close questions, @Јοеу. Perhaps it is paid with repo points, I have never tried and don't want to...

Comment: Apparently it's been re-opened by now. And you don't get anything for closing questions, except maybe a smug grin on your face. Many times it's warranted, but every now an then there's a few people closing questions without knowing the subject matter at all (or suggesting edits to posts which then are approved by people who know nothing as well ...).